# Is there a way to resolve or configure the container to resolve a default object if one isn't found?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I would like to be able to inject a `DefaultService` object that implements `IService<in T>`.

For example if I've got a constructor:

`public FunClient(IDefaultService<FunModel> service) { ... }`

But I don't have a `FunService : IService<FunModel>` developed, I would like to be able to tell Autofac to not throw an exception, but instead resolve/inject a `DefaultService` instance.

Comment: How *autofac* should find the default implementation of the interface. You can do a *RegistrationSource* to provide it but which *Type* should Autofac choose ?

Comment: What is the relationship between `DefaultService` and `IDefaultService<T>` and between `IService<in T>` and `IDefaultService<T>`?

Comment: @CyrilDurand  What do you mean by "you can do a RegistrationSource to provide"? The type could be any type that isn't registered in autofac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the registration of open generic types. You will have to create a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) implementation for `IDefaultService<T>` and register that using `RegisterGeneric`, as follows:

```
public class NullDefaultService<T> : IDefaultService<T> {
   // Implement methods here
}

// registration
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NullDefaultService<>))
    .As(typeof(IDefaultService<>));
```

Comment: I have tried this, but how would `IDefaultService<>` look as a constructor parameter?

Comment: @edhedges: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In my question I have `public FunClient(IDefaultService<FunModel> service) { ... }`. The goal is to configure autofac or write some sort of extension if need be to have `NullDefaultService` be resolved when the container can't find anything registered for `IDefaultService<FunModel>`.

Comment: @edhedges: Did you try my suggestion? That is exactly what `RegisterGeneric` does. It functions as fallback mechanism in case there is no other registration.

Comment: I did try it, but it could have been that I didn't set it up correctly with some of my existing registrations. I'll give it another shot, thanks.

Comment: Looks like it worked, thanks! I actually had that registration, but my implementation of `DefaultService` was incorrect and I was getting an exception when the builder was building the container.